# django : url change depends on model exist

Tags: django

I'd like to make user access to page depends on model exist. and I use CBV.

Do I have to control views? or urls?

Is FBV only way to control url?

How can I control user access url? hope kindly help me.

i'd like to control for example:(as you know, this is invalid syntax. hope you know what i'm saying.)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views, models

app_name = "papers"


    urlpatterns = [
        path(
            "memberagreement/<int:preassociation_pk>/",
            {% if models.MemberAgreement.association.get(pk=preassociaion_pk) is not NULL %}
                views.member_agreement_detail_vc.as_view(),
            {% else %}
                views.member_agreement_create_vc.as_view(),
            {% endif %}
            name="member_agreement_vc",
        )
    ]
```

I add my views.py:(it works when models is exist, but if model does not exist, i can't load my template...)

```
def member_agreement_vc(request, preassociation_pk):
    preassociation = preassociation_models.Preassociation.objects.get(
        pk=preassociation_pk
    )
    try:
        member_agreement = models.MemberAgreement.objects.get(pk=1)
        return render(
            request,
            "papers/member_agreement/detail.html",
            {"member_agreement": member_agreement},
        )
    except models.MemberAgreement.DoesNotExist:
        form_class = forms.CreateMemberAgreementFormVC
        template_name = "papers/member_agreement/create.html"

        def form_valid(self, form):
            pk = self.kwargs.get("preassociation_pk")
            member_agreement = form.save()
            # content
            # association
            # writer
            # participants
            # category
            # is_business
            # is_general

            # number_of_investment_account
            # name
            # resident_registration_number
            # address
            # contact
            member_agreement.writer = self.request.user
            member_agreement.association = preassociation_models.Preassociation.objects.get(
                pk=pk
            )
            member_agreement.category = "member_agreement"
            member_agreement.is_business = True
            member_agreement.is_general = False

            member_agreement.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect(
                reverse(
                    "preassociations:paper",
                    kwargs={"pk": member_agreement.association.pk},
                )
            )
```

Comment: URLs are loaded once in Django and this is not possible. Apart from that, I would suggest writing this logic inside your view

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but how can I control create and detail(?) using CBV whether models exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking, I think is not possible. `URL` is just a path, or a way you will do nothing in there except walking. Just like you are new to a road, you will just walk, then when you have to decide where to go, either you will ask google to do so, or the nearby person. So, road is like `url` and google map is like `views` where you will decide where to go.

I am going to try it the views ways then,

```
// urls.py 

// Add your path

// views.py
from .models import YourModel         // import model

def decideWhereToGo(request):
    modelExist = YourModel.objects.filter(someField=someValue).exists()
    if modelExist:
        // Do sthg
    else:
        // redirect to the url where you want to send if model does not exists
```

Comment: Actually, I hope to know is it possible to using forms in FBV.